# I'm trying to create an active state for a div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create an active state for a div.

Got the hover working but when i'm on the page in question the active won't show.
What i'm trying to implement is the same style as the hover.

Here's the css for the div.

```
    #fp-design a { width: 240px; height: 47px; float: left; display: block; background:url(images/assets/break.jpg) no-repeat; background-position: top right; }
#fp-design a:hover { height: 44px; border-bottom: 3px solid #d3028e; text-decoration:none; }
#fp-design a:active { height: 44px; border-bottom: 3px solid #d3028e; text-decoration:none; }
#fp-design h2 { height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 4px 0 0 12px; text-align: left; color: #FFF; text-decoration:none; }
#fp-design h3 { height: 11px; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 12px; text-align: left; color: #FFF; text-decoration:none; }
```

Here's the page code

```
<div id="fp-design">
   <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/web-design/"><h2>WEB DESIGN</h2>
   <h3>PROFESSIONAL WEBSITE DESIGN</h3></a>
</div>
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

a:active means "is being clicked". Not "is loaded". is that what you are after?

It somewhat reads as if you want the div to change appearance if a page is being viewed. in order to do that you'll need to add a class to the div, the hover/active states won't do it. a:link = link sitting on a page, a:visited = a link that has been clicked previously, a:hover = a link when the mouse is over it, a:active = a link when the mouse clicks on it.